# unable to set names in xlsxwriter chart legend

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying to name the data in my chart legend but I only get "Column B", "Column A", etc.  I have tried starting the data at row 0 (where the titles are) as well as starting at row 1 (where the data actually starts).  It doesn't really seem to matter what I give the 'name' entry in the json package passed to add_series():

```
    # add the data to the workbook:
    date_col = 0
    value_col = 1
    buy_action_col = 2
    sell_action_col = 3
    net_worth_col = 4
    last_row = len(date_data)
    title_row = 0
    data_start_row = 1
    titles = ['Action Date', 'Value', 'Buy', 'Sell', 'Net Worth']
    worksheet.write_row(0, 0, titles)
    worksheet.write_column(title_row + 1, date_col, data=date_data)
    worksheet.write_column(title_row + 1, value_col, data=value_data)
    worksheet.write_column(title_row + 1, buy_action_col, data=buy_action_data)
    worksheet.write_column(title_row + 1, sell_action_col, data=sell_action_data)
    worksheet.write_column(title_row + 1, net_worth_col, data=net_worth_data)
    date_format = {'num_format': 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM'}
    fmt = workbook.add_format(date_format)
    worksheet.set_column('A:A', None, fmt)
    worksheet.set_column(data_start_row, date_col, 15)

    # create the chart and add it to the workbook:
    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
    chart.set_y_axis({'name': 'Values'})
    chart.set_y2_axis({'name': 'Worth'})
    chart.set_x_axis({'name': 'Time'})
    chart.set_title({'name': 'Chart of {}'.format(historical_data.symbol)})
    # add values
    chart.add_series({
        'name': titles[value_col],
        'line': {
            'color': 'cyan',
            'width': .5
        },
        'values': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, value_col, last_row, value_col],
        'categories': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, date_col, last_row, date_col],
    })
    # add net worth
    chart.add_series({
        'name': titles[net_worth_col],
        'line': {
            'color': 'blue',
            'width': .5
        },
        'values': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, net_worth_col, last_row, net_worth_col],
        'categories': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, date_col, last_row, date_col],
        'y2_axis': 1,
    })
    # add buys
    chart.add_series({
        # 'name': titles[buy_action_col],
        'marker': {
            'type': 'long_dash',
            'size': 8,
            'border': {'color': 'red'},
            'fill': {'color': 'red'},
        },
        'values': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, buy_action_col, last_row, buy_action_col],
        'categories': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, date_col, last_row, date_col],
    })
    # add sells
    chart.add_series({
        # 'name': titles[sell_action_col],
        'marker': {
            'type': 'plus',
            'size': 8,
            'border': {'color': 'green'},
            'fill': {'color': 'green'},
        },
        'name': "sells",
        'values': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, sell_action_col, last_row, sell_action_col],
        'categories': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, date_col, last_row, date_col],
    })
    chart.set_size({'width': 720, 'height': 576})
    chart.set_legend({'position': 'top'})
    chart.set_x_axis({
        'date_axis': True,
        'min': date_data[0],
        'max': date_data[len(date_data)-1]
    })
    worksheet.insert_chart('A2', chart)
    workbook.close()
```

Here is the output chart (legend circled in red):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code with some simple sample data and I got the expected output, see below:

[image]

Update: from the comments below it looks like the issue was with OpenOffice.

Comment: Well that is interesting... It's not working for me :-/

Comment: I wonder where it is getting the "Column A", "Column B", etc from?

Comment: There is nothing in XlsxWriter that would or could generate series names like “Column X”. Are you using Excel and if so which version?  Also how many points per series are you plotting?

Comment: Is there any way to manually put the titles of the data into the legend?

Comment: In that case it is probably an OpenOffice issue. Could you check using Excel?

Comment: Just noticed the question on the number of points.  There are 5,439 points in each series

Comment: I retried with 5500 points per series and don't see any issue in Excel.

Comment: OK - open office was the problem!  For some reason open office does not work the same way.  Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Open Office does not always work the same was as Excel.  I opened the same file with Excel and it looks correct